# Oracle xmlagg get correct output

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a dynamic pivot for some columns in a table. Normally, it goes smoothly with a listagg but in this case, since the resulting variable was greater than 3K characters, I had to go with xmlagg. However, I'm not able to get the output as

```
'COLUMN' as "COLUMN"
```

so I can then pivot the columns just I'm used to do with listagg.

```
SELECT
    rtrim(XMLAGG(xmlelement(e, ''''
                               || agr_name
                               || ''' as "'
                               || agr_name
                               || '"', ', ').extract('//text()')
        ORDER BY
            agr_name
    ).getclobval(), ', ') agr_name
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            agr_name
        FROM
            dat_skills
    );
```

What I'm getting instead is

```
&apos;COLUMN; as &quot;COLUMN;,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xmlcast` - it will solve several of your problems. I don't have your table, but here is how it works on a different one:

```
SELECT
    rtrim(xmlcast(XMLAGG(xmlelement(e, ''''
                               || object_type
                               || ''' as "'
                               || object_type
                               || '"', ', ')
        ORDER BY
            object_type) as clob), ', ')
    object_type
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            object_type
        FROM
            user_objects
    );

OBJECT_TYPE                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'FUNCTION' as "FUNCTION", 'INDEX' as "INDEX", 'LIBRARY' as "LIBRARY", 'LOB' as "
LOB", 'PROCEDURE' as "PROCEDURE", 'SEQUENCE' as "SEQUENCE", 'TABLE' as "TABLE", 
'TYPE' as "TYPE", 'TYPE BODY' as "TYPE BODY", 'VIEW' as "VIEW"
```

You no longer need to extract text (cast as CLOB does that already), you don't need to worry about escaping and unescaping, and the result is a CLOB as you need it to be.

Comment: Brilliant as always. I've tried and this works with cols as varchar2 as well. Is it preferrable to keep it as clob? What would be the difference?

Comment: If it works as varchar2 that's even better. Only keep it as CLOB if you expect that in the future you will have more values in that column. But, if it works as varchar2, it should also work with LISTAGG, did you try? Yesterday it wouldn't work, because you didn't realize you should only aggregate the **distinct** values from the column. With that added, perhaps LISTAGG is enough and you don't need any of these complications.

Comment: No, I tried at first with just the distinct values and the resulting string was over 5k chars that's why I had to go with this xmlagg. In my original question I forgot to change it back to select distinct, but I had already tried it.

Comment: @JaviTorre Then how is it possible that with `xmlagg` you can get a varchar2? Something doesn't seem right.

Comment: If I declare a varchar2(7000) it works. If I declare a varchar2(6000), it gives ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error. The limit for listagg I think it was somewhere between 4k and 5k.

Comment: @JaviTorre - OK, I understand. Your db is set up with extended varchar2 size (32,767 bytes). However, when Oracle introduced this, they didn't change LISTAGG - the limit is still 4000 bytes even when the db has extended varchar2 size. Then it may be better to keep as CLOB, since at some point you may exceed 32k too. Besides, you are only creating the view once (or perhaps a few times), so performance shouldn't be an issue. However, see if you run into any other problems later in your project, and keep the varchar2 option in mind.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I'll keep it as a clob and monitor it.

Answer (score 1):

Include call to `UTL_I18N.unescape_reference`:

```
SELECT UTL_I18N.unescape_reference (
          XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (
                     e,
                     '''' || agr_name || ''' as "' || agr_name || '"',
                     ', ').EXTRACT ('//text()')
                  ORDER BY agr_name).getclobval ()) agr_name
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT agr_name
          FROM dat_skills);
```

---

**With**:

```
SQL> SELECT UTL_I18N.unescape_reference (
  2            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (
  3                       e,
  4                       '''' || agr_name || ''' as "' || agr_name || '"',
  5                       ', ').EXTRACT ('//text()')
  6                    ORDER BY agr_name).getclobval ()) agr_name
  7    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT agr_name
  8            FROM dat_skills);

AGR_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'ACCOUNTING' as "ACCOUNTING", 'OPERATIONS' as "OPERATIONS", 'RESEARCH' as "RESEA
RCH", 'SALES' as "SALES",
```

**Without**:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (
  3                       e,
  4                       '''' || agr_name || ''' as "' || agr_name || '"',
  5                       ', ').EXTRACT ('//text()')
  6                    ORDER BY agr_name).getclobval () agr_name
  7    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT dname agr_name
  8            FROM dept);

AGR_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
&apos;ACCOUNTING&apos; as &quot;ACCOUNTING&quot;, &apos;OPERATIONS&apos; as &quo

SQL>
```

Comment: It's now throwing this error: ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 9692, maximum: 4000)
22835. 00000 -  "Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: %s, maximum: %s)"

Comment: `escape_reference` only works on varchar2, it does not work on CLOB.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have any other characters that need unescaping, you can replace `&quot;` and `&apos;` them with the actual quotes:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           RTRIM(
             XMLAGG(
               xmlelement(
                 e,
                 '''' || agr_name || ''' as "' || agr_name || '"',
                 ', '
               ).extract('//text()')
               ORDER BY agr_name
             ).getclobval(),
             ', '
           ),
           '&quot;',
           '"'
         ),
         '&apos;',
         ''''
       ) AS agr_name
FROM   (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                agr_name
         FROM   dat_skills
       );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=45e9be34617d73a2da8443a7f09cd1f1)*

Comment: In principle, the problem with this approach is that the string values in the OP's `agr_name` column may already contain substrings like `'&quot;`, and those should not be converted to quotes. `xmlcast` avoids that problem. (This is unlikely to happen in real life, unless the data is specifically related to html or xml, but in theory it can happen.)

Comment: Of course, if the values contained substrings like `&quot;` then there would be even more characters to escape and un-escape; but the problem would be the same.